# Why can't my read-only user role see any of my tables' primary key information in psql?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, access-control, read-only-database

I have a PostgreSQL database on Azure, and I've created a readonly_user role that allows for external parties to connect to the db in a read-only capacity using a connection string.

This readonly_user has been granted SELECT privileges, and it also has USAGE access on the public schema.

However, the tables in my database have composite primary keys. When I am logged in as the admin user, I can access these primary keys with the following command:

```
SELECT                                     
    tc.table_schema,
    tc.table_name,
    kcu.column_name
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints tc
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
WHERE
    tc.table_name = 'player_data' AND
    tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY';
```

For some reason, no matter how I try to play with the usage and access roles for readonly_user, this command (and others like it) to access the primary key information for the db tables *always* returns 0 rows. There should be at least 3 for every table, which I see clearly when I issue this command connected as the admin role.

Is there something about a read-only user that limits its access to the information_schema? How can I access the primary keys of a table as a read-only user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. The SQL standard defines (ISO/IEC 9075-11:2003, 5.58):

```
CREATE VIEW TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS
...
    WHERE ( TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME ) IN
            ( SELECT TP.TABLE_CATALOG, TP.TABLE_SCHEMA, TP.TABLE_NAME
              FROM DEFINITION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES AS TP
              WHERE TP.PRIVILEGE_TYPE <> 'SELECT'
                AND
                    ( TP.GRANTEE IN
                      ( 'PUBLIC', CURRENT_USER )
                   OR
                      TP.GRANTEE IN
                      ( SELECT ROLE_NAME
                        FROM ENABLED_ROLES ) )
```

That is, users who only have the `SELECT` privilege on an object don't see entries in `information_schema.table_constraints`.

There are several possible solutions:

- Give the `readonly_user` the `REFERENCES` privilege on all tables. That is harmless, as long as it doesn't have `CREATE` on any schema and `TEMP` on the database.
- Query the system catalog tables `pg_class` and `pg_constraint` in `pg_catalog`.
- Create a `SECURITY DEFINER` function with `SET search_path = information_schema` that runs your query and is owned by a privileged user. `readonly_user` can then call this function to get the information.

Comment: Thank you! This is very clear. Interestingly, I managed to get around it in the following way:

SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'player_data';

was available to the readonly_user role. Still, I am glad to know the table constraints are not available with SELECT alone. I will try the REFERENCES privilege if I need it.

Comment: Interesting! The standard says that *The KEY_COLUMN_USAGE table has one or more rows for each row in the TABLE_CONSTRAINTS table
that has a CONSTRAINT_TYPE of “UNIQUE”, “PRIMARY KEY”, or “FOREIGN KEY”.* So it could be argued that the definition in PostgreSQL is incorrect. But given that `pg_constraint` is public, I doubt that anybody cares.